# Sitecore Language Embedding In Multi Language Site

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have one multi language application in Sitecore.
Default language is "en". Requirement is "en" should not be display in URL.
I can use Langauge Embedding "Never" here, but it will cause problem for other language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create yourself a new LinkProvider and set `options.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Never` for "en" only, all other languages will then use whatever is set in your config:

```
public class LinkProvider : Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider
{
    private static readonly Language neverEmbeddedLanguage = Language.Parse("en");

    public override string GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
    {
        if (item.Language == neverEmbeddedLanguage)
        {
            options.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Never;
        }
        return base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
    }
}
```

Then register your new LinkProvider as the default one (use a patch include file):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <linkManager>
      <patch:attribute name="defaultProvider">custom</patch:attribute>
      <providers>
        <add name="custom" 
             type="MyProject.Custom.Links.LinkProvider, MyProject.Custom" languageEmbedding="always" ... />
      </providers>
    </linkManager>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:**

As RvanDylan correctly points out, we also need to handle the incoming requests now that we have language embedding disabled for a particular language. By default if no language code is embedded in the url or sc_lang parameter passed, Sitecore will fall back to using the Language cookie. So if a user visited a url, "/fr/contact" and visited "/contact" then they would be served French content by default. We need to handle this and tell Sitecore that empty actually means English. We can do this by overrriding the logic in the `StripLanguage` processor in the `preprocessRequest` pipeline:

```
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Globalization;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest;
using Sitecore.Web;

namespace MyProject.Custom.Pipelines.preprocessRequest
{
    public class StripLanguage : Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.StripLanguage
    {
        private static readonly Language defaultLanguage = Language.Parse("en");

        public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");           
            string language = WebUtil.ExtractLanguageName(args.Context.Request.FilePath);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
            {
                Sitecore.Context.Language = defaultLanguage;
                Sitecore.Context.Data.FilePathLanguage = defaultLanguage;
                return;
            }

            base.Process(args);
        }
    }
}
```

And the associated patch config file to go with this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <preprocessRequest>
        <processor type="MyProject.Custom.Pipelines.preprocessRequest.StripLanguage, MyProject.Custom" 
                   patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.StripLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </preprocessRequest>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This fixes generating urls. Might also need to override the Languageresolver in case a url without language is requested which should result in English but will result in something else if sc_lang cookie tells us something else.

Comment: @RvanDalen Yes, that's true. I'll update shortly to include that info too

Answer (score 1):

I would always strongly advise to embed the language in the url.

That being said, you could:

Create language switch urls using ?sc_lang=en in the querystring. The language will then be persisted in a SC cookie and you can happily browse further with that language.

Or have a postback and set the the language like so (the true param will persist the language in a cookie:

```
Sitecore.Context.SetLanguage(Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse("en"), true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to hide "en" but for other language should be in URL.
like ..
if "en" xyz.com/page1
if "au" xyz.com/au/page1

Comment: Ok, then jammykam has a good solution for generating urls + the switching link provider might be necessary as Jan Bluemink suggests.

Answer (score 0):

An options is to Create a Sitecore LinkProvider to use different LinkManager configurations.

See [change-linkmanager-config](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/change-linkmanager-config/)

The new Sitecore Linkprovider for mixed configuration with multilanguage and not multilanguage websites change the LanguageEmbedding depend on the current site.

Or you can make a switching provider [A Switching Link Provider in Sitecore](http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.nl/2014/02/a-switching-link-provider.html)